# Java OOP instantiate self or add subclass?

Tags: java, oop

So the main animal class will generate som cows, but the instantiation is made in the cow class. My question is: Is this code pattern really "ok"? Or should the cow class be renamed to "CowHandler" and instead have a subclass named cow?

CowHandler would then have a field `List<Cow> cows;` and Cow class only `String name;`

It just feels strange for the cow class to instantiate itself, for example the field with list of cows is never used from within the cow class. 
Here is the code as of now:

**Animal class**

```
import java.util.List;

public class Animal
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        animal.init();
    }


    private void init()
    {
        Cow cow = new Cow();

        int count = cow.getCows().size();
        System.out.println("Cows in list before: " + count);

        List<Cow> manyCows = cow.makeSomeCows();

        for (Cow c : manyCows)
        {
            System.out.println(c.getName());
            System.out.println("Children?: " + c.getCows().size());
            System.out.println("");
        }

        count = cow.getCows().size();
        System.out.println("Cows in list after: " + count); 
    }
}
```

**Cow class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Cow
{
    private String name;
    private List<Cow> cows;

    public Cow()
    {   
        cows = new ArrayList<Cow>();
    }


    public List<Cow> makeSomeCows()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            Cow cow = new Cow();
            cow.name = "Tiny cow " + ((char)(i + 65));
            cows.add(cow);
        }
        return cows;
    }


    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }


    public List<Cow> getCows()
    {
        return this.cows;
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Cows in list before: 0
Tiny cow A
Children?: 0

Tiny cow B
Children?: 0

Tiny cow C
Children?: 0

Tiny cow D
Children?: 0

Tiny cow E
Children?: 0

Tiny cow F
Children?: 0

Tiny cow G
Children?: 0

Tiny cow H
Children?: 0

Tiny cow I
Children?: 0

Tiny cow J
Children?: 0

Cows in list after: 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a `private List<Cow> cows;` instance variable in the `Cow` class only makes sense if each `Cow` instance has a list of `Cow`s somehow related to it (for example, the children of that `Cow`).

If the purpose is to have a container of all the `Cow`s you created, an instance variable in the `Cow` class is wrong, since each `Cow` object would have its own `List<Cow>`.

You could use a `private static List<Cow> cows;` static variable in the `Cow` class to hold all the `Cow` instances, with corresponding `static` methods to access it, but it makes more sense to put the list on a separate container of `Cow`s, such as `CowHandler`. Note, however, that it doesn't make sense for `Cow` to be a sub-class of `CowHandler`. A `Cow` is not a `Cowhandler`.

Comment: Yes, making it a subclass doesn't make much sense either since Cow is not a CowHandler. Cow is an Animal...

Comment: I guess I can place `List<Cow> cows = new ArrayList<Cow>(); ` in the makeSomeCows() method of Cow, since no cow has a relation (yet). Thus making cow objects in the cow class is fine?

Comment: @BakedInhalf Are you saying that the `List<Cow>` will no longer be an instance variable of `Cow` class? Yes, there is no rule against creating Cow objects in the Cow class. The only potential downside is that if you had sub-classes of Cow, and you wanted your `List<Cow>` to contain objects of these sub-classes, `Cow` would not be a good place to create them, since a class shouldn't we aware of its sub-classes.

Comment: Yes that is correct, `List<Cow>` will no longer be an instance variable of Cow. One downside I see is that I can't get all cows from the Animal class. I see a scenario where I want to add more logic to cows, and add or update their properties. One class other than Animal might want to have access to all cows for example. I could pass a List<Cow> around between the classes but that is maybe not ideal?